# Rails nested_form with has_many without create additional columns in child's table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm using

```
class Mother < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :boys
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :boys, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

and

```
class Boy < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :mother

  attr_accessor :mother_id
end
```

because I can't modify columns of Boys table.

Now I create nested form in Rails but when I go to save Mother and Boys it says:

```
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError - can't write unknown attribute `mother_id`:
```

And it is normal because the column `mother_id` doesn't exists. But I don't need to save Mother model, just the many boys in the form I use with gem cocoon and then delete immediately the mother's one that I don't need anymore.

How to bypass the inexistence of column `mother_id` in boy's table and just save the boys rows without references to "fake" mother?

**Is there a way in Rails to create a form in which I can use a mechanism like Cocoon but with the same instance of the model and not a child one, without "accepts_nested_attributes_for" to be clear?**

Comment: It is meant the your will never have a mother ? so I think the existence of a Mother model is just unnecessary

Comment: Yes but I don't know how to do one form with many "rows" that are children of my fake "mother" using for example the cocoon gem. I can build in my form.html.erb the same without mother model and save many boys model at the same time with e.g. cocoon?

Comment: Why not just add the model save it and in your `create` action after save the `Boy`'s delete the mother

Comment: No, you don't understand what I mean.

Comment: Could you add your form? so I understand what you want to do?, because I really do not understand why you need a Mother model, you can just add a form for create Boys and that's it...

Comment: You can Ajaxify your Boy's form so it looks like a nested one. You do not need cocoon since you do not need to save your parent model, You are just  mired in something you do not need to, you do not need a nested form here...

Comment: I need in my boys/_form.html.erb to create many rows and each rows is a Boys model to save. Is it clear now?

Comment: Why I need to use ajax?

Comment: Allow me add an answer so you will see what Im talking about

Comment: Just a question, since you do not need to save your Mother you are not asking any data related to it, are you?

Comment: @SsouLlesS, I don't give a shit about Mother model. I need it just for save each boys model at the same time with cocoon which is beautiful.

Comment: So......? I don't understand what to do without cocoon.

Answer (score 0):

Have a `Mother` model is completely unnecessary in your case, also use cocoon is unnecessary because you do not need to save your parent model. What I would do is have a form just for create `Boy`'s and if you want it to look "nested" form, then you can Ajaxify it for give it the appearance of nested.

Delete your `Mother` model, you do not need it, then add a basic set of routes for your `Boy`

#### routes.rb

`resources :boys`

#### boys_controller.rb

```
def create
        respond_to do |format|
            @boy = Boy.new boy_params
            @boy.save
            format.js
        end
end
```

#### _form.rb

```
#just make sure you have remote: true and check that you are always creating a new Boy
<%= form_for Boy.new, builder: yourBuilder, remote: true do |f| %>
.....
<% end %>
```

Some where in your view add a div where you can show your boys and also for later append them each time you create a new one:

```
        <div id="boys">
            #Whatever collection you can get for show the current created boys I do not know, let's say current_user
            <% current_user.boys.each do |boy| %>
                <%= render boy %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
```

Next just add a script for your `create` action:

#### boys/create.js.erb

```
#If @boy is still not persisted it means it has errors, display errors
<% if @boy.new_record? %>
    $('#boy_form').append("<span class=\"error\"><%= j @boy.errors.full_messages.join(', ').html_safe %></span>");
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#new_group_goal .error').remove();
    }, 8000);
<% else %>
   #Else we prepend the @boy in the div #boys and that's it, you form is beautifully ajaxified.
    $('#boys').prepend("<%= j render(@boy) %>");
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('# .error').remove();
    }, 2000);
<% end %>
```

This way you have a unic form for create `Boy`'s with the Ajax you can add boys dynamically and it will look like a nested form, just instead of have 1 submit action you perform a submit for create all the boys, you will perform 1 submit action for each boy and display it dynamically below the form, this way is more flexible in addition to that this way has better performance. Let me know if you understood my point.

Comment: It's so difficult for me. How to save my mother model ignoring `ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError - can't write unknown attribute mother_id: ` error?

Comment: You can't do that, you know Rails uses SQL structure and SQL won't let you save an association without an id... try to implement what I gave you is your best bet.

Comment: But I can't have a list with a button like cocoon for add a row and save just at the end?

Comment: I don't understand your solution. Im sorry. I'm stucked.

Comment: I already gave you a workaround to your issue, that should be enough, I can't do more for you, sorry...

Comment: Your solution start like me. Can I save everything at the end instead of each time?